# Dynamic host name and aot

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-aot

I want to bind a dynamic class name on a component host with this kind of syntax :

```
@Component({
  host: {
    [`[class.${classNames()}]`]: 'true', 
  },
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: '...',
})
```

When I try to build with angular-cli in AOT mode, I have this error :

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically.
>   Expression form not supported

How can I make it work?

Thanks

Comment: does it work without AOT?